# How to get the full file path of an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I can get an `Assembly` object (for example using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`). How can I get its full path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var path = assembly.Location;
```

See the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location.aspx). This is the path after any shadow copying. The [`CodeBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.codebase.aspx) property will give the location before shadow-copying.

Comment: @Louis: ASP.Net uses this technique to allow assemblies to be updated, it's described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

Console.WriteLine(a.Location);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```